# Accessing params values inside a $resource param as a function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

The API I need to connect is using oData ; I need to format the request parameters before sending the request.

So I found that I can use a function as a parameter, not sure it is a best way...
I need to access the other parameters values in order to build my query. Can I do this?

Below an example, the goal is to obtain a query like this:

**Values:**

- fields = ['Username', 'Email']
- value = 'john'

**Expected result:**

`?$filter=contains(Username, 'john') or contains(Email, 'john')`

**Code:**

```
return $resource(oDataURL, {}, {
  search: {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: true,
    params: {
      fields: '',
      value: '',
      searchString: function () {
        var s = '';
        // Here! Needs to access params.fields
        _.map(params.fields, function (f, k) {
          if (k == fields.length - 1) {
            s += ' or ';
          }
          return s += 'contains(:' + f + ', \':' + value + '\')';
        });
      }
    },
    url: oDataURL + '?$filter=:searchString'
  },
```